# NTLMaps not working for shared Wifi to Burpsuite after OS X update

Tags: android, macos, proxy, ntlm, burp

So I used to use this version of [NTLMaps](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntlmaps/) to proxy shared Wifi from my Mac and redirect it to Burpsuite for Native App testing outside of an emulator. You could achieve this by setting the server.cfg to 'PARENT_PROXY:127.0.0.1', 'PARENT_PROXY_PORT:8080' & 'ALLOW_EXTERNAL_CLIENTS:1'.

But after updating to OS X, 10.11.5 the program is running but the proxied internet traffic isn't getting to burpsuite.

Part 1:
So I updated to [this version](https://github.com/heupel/ntlmaps), but that's giving me this error, "ERROR: NT DOMAIN must be set." I can find NT Domain in the server config, but I have no idea where to find this info on a mac (or would I need burpsuite?). Not a network guy could use any help finding this info.

Part 2:
Even if I get that working, that it may not fix the issue on OS X (If anyone is on OS X10.11.5 and this still works please let me know, worked couple days ago but maybe it has to do with custom settings before upgrading). Does anyone have a better way of proxying native app traffic off a real device through burp or charles (not using an emulator or by changing the app)? Or does anyone have this type of setup working on the OS X 10.11.5? I'd just roll back but my office can be pretty strict on keeping up to date so this wouldn't work as a long term solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Part 1. On a Mac, you can find you NT Network Name by going to Settings > Sharing > Hit Edit on Computer Name. It stopped the error, but not 100% sure that's right as it still can't the Wifi traffic in Burp.

> The local network name is your computer’s name with “.local” added, and any spaces are replaced with hyphens . For example, if your computer’s name is My Computer, your local network name is “My-Computer.local.” Local network names are not case sensitive, so “my-computer.local” is the same as “My-Computer.local.”

From [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18720?locale=en_US).

Part 2:
This was just stupid on my part. Looks like the OS X update changed the default server address for shared wifi, it's now 192.168.2.1. So I simply needed to update the manual settings for the Wifi connection on the devices to use 192.168.2.1 for Proxy hostname and keep the port the port at 5865.